# UNWIND with child UNWIND producing wrong nodes and relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I expect this query to produce 7 nodes with 21 relationships.

It produces 13 nodes and 6 relationships

```
WITH [{address: "1", connections: []},
{address: "2",connections: ["1"]},
{address: "3",connections: ["1", "2"]},
{address: "4",connections: ["1", "2", "3"]},
{address: "5",connections: ["1", "2", "3", "4"]},
{address: "6",connections: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]},
{address: "7",connections: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]}] AS seeds
UNWIND seeds AS seed
MERGE (source:Address { address: seed.address })

WITH seed.connections AS connections
UNWIND connections AS connection
MATCH (target:Address) WHERE target.address = connection

MERGE (source)-[:CONNECTS_TO]->(target)
```

I tried a dozen+ variations including FOREACH.

Am I wrong thinking this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very close, there is one thing we need to correct for this query to work as expected: the scope of your `source` variable. This goes out of scope in the middle of your query on the WITH:

```
...
WITH seed.connections AS connections
...
```

`source` isn't included in the WITH, so it goes out of scope. The `source` in your the last line in your MERGE isn't bound to any prior node, so where such a pattern doesn't exist between some node and the target, a new blank node will be created as the starting node of the relationship.

To fix this, we need to include `source` in your WITH so it stays in scope:

```
...
WITH source, seed.connections AS connections
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Will test immediately.

Comment: 100% perfect. I tried passing in other things like `seed.address` and, obviously, could not find the magic. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As @InverseFalcon describes, the final query looks like this

```
WITH [{address: "1", connections: []},
{address: "2",connections: ["1"]},
{address: "3",connections: ["1", "2"]},
{address: "4",connections: ["1", "2", "3"]},
{address: "5",connections: ["1", "2", "3", "4"]},
{address: "6",connections: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]},
{address: "7",connections: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]}] AS seeds
UNWIND seeds AS seed
MERGE (source:Address { address: seed.address })

WITH source, seed.connections AS connections
UNWIND connections AS connection
MATCH (target:Address) WHERE target.address = connection

MERGE (source)-[:CONNECTS_TO]->(target)
```